# XPath to select all elements between two headings?

Tags: html, xml, xpath

```
<h2>Headline 1</h2>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some more text</p>
<ul>
<li>list item 1</li>
<li>list item 2</li>
</ul>
<p>more text</p>
<h2>Headline 2</h2>
```

I have the above in a webpage and I want to be able to target all elements following the first `h2` that contains the text `'Headline 1'` up to but NOT including the element `h2` that contains the text `'Headline 2'`.

I can target the elements like this:

```
//*[count(preceding-sibling::hr)=1]
```

but this is not specific to the text contained and so if the page ever changed then the xpath could be pointing to something totally different.

What I would like in sudo code terms is this:

> give me all the elements between the header `'Headline 1'` and the
>   header `'Headline 2'` including `'Headline 1'`

Is this at all possible?

Answer (score 3):

This XPath,

```
//*[    preceding-sibling::h2[. = 'Headline 1'] 
    and following-sibling::h2[. = 'Headline 2']]
```

will select all elements between `h2`s with string values of `'Headline 1'` and `'Headline 2'`:

```
<p>some text</p>
<p>some more text</p>
<ul>
<li>list item 1</li>
<li>list item 2</li>
</ul>
<p>more text</p>
```

---

Andersson points out in the comments that OP wants the first `h2` included in the selection.

Andersson's initial thought would work:

```
//h2[. = 'Headline 1'] |
//*[    preceding-sibling::h2[. = 'Headline 1'] 
    and following-sibling::h2[. = 'Headline 2']]
```

Here's another way:

```
//*[self::h2[. = 'Headline 1']
    or (    preceding-sibling::h2[. = 'Headline 1'] 
        and following-sibling::h2[. = 'Headline 2']]
```

Or, probably the ideal way:

```
//h2[. = 'Headline 2']
    /preceding-sibling::*[not(following-sibling::h2[. = 'Heading 1'])]
```

because it avoids having to specify `'Heading 1'` twice.

Answer (score 0):

What if try something like

```
//*[text()="Headline 1"]/following-sibling::*
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//h2[contains(.,'Headline 1')]//*
```

Will return every element below the header.  You could further narrow it down with

```
//h2[contains(.,'Headline 1')]//p
```

for paragraph text, but that would not include the li elements.

Comment: After taking a second look at the HTML code I used for my test, I realize now that it was inside a <span>.  You are obviously correct, thank you for pointing it out.