# XPath to select all paragraphs between two headers?

Tags: html, xml, xpath

I am trying to all `p` elements located between two `h5` elements. The starting `h5` text is "Subject" and the second `h5` text is "tenders file".

You may see the picture attached as well.

I don't want to have other `p` elements which are coming after the second `h5`.
[image]

I have tried the following XPath:

```
//p[preceding-sibling::h5//*[contains(text() , 'SUBJECT')]  and following-sibling::h5//*[contains(text() , 'Tender’s Files,')]] trying to get idea from [enter link description here][2]
```

but could not get the right paragraphs.  It still selects other paragraphs after the second `h5`.

```
<div>
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" width="90%">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="vertical-align: middle;" colspan="2" width="90%">
<h5 style="padding-left: 10px;"><strong><span style="color: #3577be;">Tender Title:</span>&nbsp;Testing of Non-Fortified Wheat Flour in NES</strong></h5>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="vertical-align: middle;" width="45%">
<h5 style="padding-left: 10px;"><strong><span style="color: #3577be;">Tender No:</span>&nbsp;SYRIA-TA-2021-005</strong></h5>
</td>
<td style="vertical-align: middle;">
<h5 style="padding-left: 10px;"><strong><span style="color: #3577be;">Location:</span> North East Syria</strong></h5>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="vertical-align: middle;" colspan="2">
<h5 style="padding-left: 10px;"><strong><span style="color: #3577be;">Tender Package Available from:</span>&nbsp;2021-01-10</strong></h5>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="vertical-align: middle;" colspan="2">
<h5 style="padding-left: 10px;"><strong><span style="color: #3577be;">Deadline for Offer Submission:</span> 2021-01-18 17:00 (Iraqi Time)</strong></h5>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<table class="table " width="90%">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<h5><strong><u>SUBJECT:</u></strong>&nbsp;<strong>Testing of Non-Fortified Wheat Flour in NES</strong></h5>
<p>Our organization, a non-profit organization, provides humanitarian assistance to “people in need”, is seeking quotations from eligible contractors to&nbsp;<strong>Testing of Non-Fortified Wheat Flour in NES</strong>. Our organization anticipates awarding Multiple or Single contract(s) as a result of this Solicitation. Our organization reserves the right to award more or none under this RFQ.</p>
<p>All bids shall be submitted&nbsp;<strong>via e-mail to</strong>&nbsp;<span id="cloak1f9ac73a082c1f52174ccee4f406b81c"><a href="mailto:Syr-tendering@blumont.org"><strong>Syr-tendering@blumont.org</strong></a></span>&nbsp;<strong>as PDF format and clearly written the subject of the tender</strong>&nbsp;This RFQ is in no way obligates our organization Our organization to award a contract nor does it commit our organization to pay any cost incurred in the preparation and submission of a proposal.</p>
<p>Our organization bears no responsibility for data errors resulting from transmission or conversion processes.</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<ul>
<li><strong>To help us with our procurement effort, please indicate in your email where (ngotenders.net) you saw this tender/procurement notice.</strong></li>
</ul>
<p><strong>Sincerely</strong></p>
<p><strong>Procurement Committee</strong></p>
<h5><strong>Tender’s Files,</strong></h5>
<h5><strong><a href="https://www.ngosjobs-bids.com/index.php/submit-tender/submission-view-file/73abcfe286e504282bdac61776e50907/ec8dde28a94a8fde67c09e244f6bb8a0">5ffb04ba52a49-005-announcement.zip</a>,&nbsp;</strong></h5>
<hr>
<h5 dir="rtl"><strong><u>الموضوع</u></strong><strong><u>:</u></strong>&nbsp;<strong>فحص الطحين الغير مدعم في شمال شرق سوريا.</strong><strong>&nbsp;</strong></h5>
<p dir="rtl">منظمتنا و هي منظمة غير ربحية تعمل لخدمة المنكوبين في العالم و تسعى للحصول على عروض أسعار من المقاولين المؤهلين لغرض الموضوع:&nbsp;<strong>فحص الطحين الغير مدعم في شمال شرق سوريا.</strong>&nbsp;وتتوقع منظمتنا منح (عقود) متعددة أو مفردة نتيجة لهذا الطلب. وتحتفظ منظمتنا بالحق في منح التعاقد بأكثر أو أقل من المتوقع للطلب أعلاه.</p>
<p dir="rtl">لهذا الطلب. وتحتفظ منظمتنا بالحق في منح التعاقد بأكثر أو أقل من المتوقع للطلب أعلاه.</p>
<p dir="rtl">&nbsp;يجب على جميع مقدمي العطاءات تقديم العروض عبر الايميل :<strong>عبر الايميل:&nbsp;</strong><span id="cloakc42a61e471daa10a7992dbd8b44f9b26"><a href="mailto:Syr-tendering@blumont.org"><strong>Syr-tendering@blumont.org</strong></a></span>&nbsp;<strong>و بصيغة</strong><strong>&nbsp;PDF</strong>&nbsp;و تم التوضيح للموضوع المناقصة بان المنظمة لا تلتزم بأي حال من الأحوال بمنح العقد كما أن المنظمة لا تلتزم بدفع أي تكاليف متكبدة في إعداد وتقديم العرض.</p>
<p dir="rtl">كما ان منظمتنا لا تتحمل أية مسؤولية عن أي أخطاء في البيانات الناتجة عن عمليات النقل أو التحويل او المحادثة.</p>
<p dir="rtl">
</p><p dir="rtl"><strong>مع فائق الاحترام &nbsp;و التقدير</strong></p>
<p dir="rtl"><strong>لجنة المشتريات</strong></p>
<h5><strong>Tender’s Files,</strong></h5>
<h5><strong><a href="https://www.ngosjobs-bids.com/index.php/submit-tender/submission-view-file/73abcfe286e504282bdac61776e50907/ec8dde28a94a8fde67c09e244f6bb8a0">5ffb04ba52a49-005-announcement.zip</a>,&nbsp;</strong></h5>
</div>
```

the page source code.

[enter link description here](https://ngotenders.net/tenders/testing-of-non-fortified-wheat-flour-in-nes/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using techniques from the following Q/A:

- [XPath to select all elements between two headings?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43122455/290085)
- [Testing text() nodes vs string values in XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34593753/290085)

The following XPath,

```
//p[    preceding-sibling::h5[starts-with(normalize-space(),'SUBJECT:')]
    and following-sibling::h5[normalize-space()='Tender’s Files,']]
```

will select all `p` elements between your two targeted headlines, as requested.

---

### Update after OP included actual markup:

Your actual markup includes duplicate

```
<h5><strong>Tender’s Files,</strong></h5>
```

headings.  The above XPath will select through to the *last* such heading.

If you want to select through only the *first* such heading, use this XPath instead:

```
//p[    preceding-sibling::h5[starts-with(normalize-space(),'SUBJECT:')]
    and following-sibling::h5[normalize-space()='Tender’s Files,']
    and not(preceding-sibling::h5[normalize-space()='Tender’s Files,'])]
```

Comment: thank you for your support. I tried to use your code but I still can't get the paragraphs located between that two h5 elements. I updated my question and also mentioned the link to the page.could you please give me a hand with the solution

Comment: Thanks for adding the markup as text to your question.  I've now confirmed that the XPath I provided [does as you request](http://xpather.com/bAiKT68o), but in your actual markup there are two `<h5><strong>Tender’s Files,</strong></h5>`, and the provided XPath will include the inner such `h5` in the selection.  Did you only want the elements between the `SUBJECT` `h5` and the ***first*** `Tender’s Files,` `h5`?

Answer (score 1):

Your xpath should work if you add this:

```
//p[preceding-sibling::h5//*[contains(text() , 'SUBJECT')]  and (following-sibling:: h5//*[contains(text() , 'Tender’s Files,')])[2]]
```