# how to select elements between two h tags containg some text using xpath

Tags: xpath

I am trying to get texts of all p which is located between two h5. starting h5 text is "Subject" and the second h5 text is "tenders file'.

you may see the picture attached as well.

I don't want to have others p which is coming after the second h5.
[image]

I have tried the following code :

```
//p[preceding-sibling::h5//*[contains(text() , 'SUBJECT')]  and following-sibling::h5//*[contains(text() , 'Tender’s Files,')]]
```

using the following question
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43122455/xpath-to-select-all-elements-between-two-headings)

but could not get the right paragraphs, it still selects other paragraphs coming after the second h5.

Comment: Do not re-post the same question that you just posted and had closed as a duplicate.  Edit it and request that it be reopened if you feel that the provided duplicate does not answer your question.

Comment: I have re-opened your previous question and provided an answer there.

Comment: @kjhughes I didn't know this